# Run-time error '91

Tags: vba, excel

I keep getting an error:

> Run-time error '91; Object variable or with block variable not set.

My script runs fine and does what it needs to do but I can't figure out how to get rid of this error.

Thank you for the help.

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("F24:I24")

    rng.Select

    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Must insert Temperature you dingus!")
    Else
        rng = TextBox1.Text
        Call GetCabinet1
    End If

    Unload Me

End Sub

Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = Sheets("Executive Summary")

    wb.Activate
    ws.Select

    UserForm1.Show

    Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line errors?

Comment: What's `GetCabinet1`?

Comment: That said, your question is incomplete. **Many** things can go wrong with this code, we need to know what specific instruction is throwing the error.

Comment: @SJR there is no specific line....it gets all the way through and then throws the error.

Comment: @BruceWayne It is a script that pulls copies from one workbook and pastes the data in another column. It does a few other things but that is the main thing.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thank you for your instruction...I am still green at this and I appreciate all the guidance I can get.

Comment: Start with removing these `Unload Me` traps ;-)

Comment: I will definitely stay away from those unload me traps and learned more about how toxic select and activate commands can be..... thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove all those `Unload.Me` from both your subs and place it in the sub calling that userform

place a `Me.Hide` by the end of CommandButton1_Click(), instead

finally remove `UserForm1.Show` from `UserForm_Initialize` since it'd make it repeat twice

so your "Main" sub would look like:

```
Sub main()

    Dim UF As UserForm1

    Set UF = New UserForm1
    UF.Show
    Unload UF ' unload the userform from here

End Sub
```

and your userform1 code like:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("F24:I24")

    rng.Select

    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Must insert Temperature you dingus!")
    Else
        rng = TextBox1.Text
        Call GetCabinet1
    End If

    Me.Hide

End Sub


Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = Sheets("Executive Summary")

    wb.Activate
    ws.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes I did.... the code works. The main problem seemed to be the unload me traps. I now understand the error of execution I was initially trying. Thank you so much for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Simply replacing the unload me with me.hide fixed my problem... Thank you to all of those who gave their input....